# No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key/unresolved'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I have defined a OData function as below:

```
var function = builder.EntityType<User>().Function("GetContacts").ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<Contact>("Contacts");
```

I have then defined a method on my UsersController as below:

```
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("Users({key})/Default.GetContacts()")]
public IHttpActionResult GetContacts([FromODataUri]Guid key)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

On trying to access this from a client:

http://localhost/odata/Users(874C0BC3-6D9B-4DFA-B42C-8403FE1B281D)/GetContacts

The controller is hit but the method isn't, instead in postman I get back an exception "No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key/unresolved'."

I have tried:

http://localhost/odata/Users(874C0BC3-6D9B-4DFA-B42C-8403FE1B281D)/GetContacts()

I've removed the explicit setting of the ODataRouteAttribute and relying on the built-in routing convention but still no luck.

I've also tried removing "Default." from the ODataRouteAttribute but this throws a server error when trying to launch the application "Found an unresolved path segment 'GetContacts()' in the OData path template 'Users({key})/GetContacts()'."

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?  Or is there a way you can show me to debug these types of routing issues so I can solve the problem myself?

Appreciate any help you can give.

p.s. I am using OData v4.

Comment: I should have been calling http://localhost/odata/Users(874C0BC3-6D9B-4DFA-B42C-8403FE1B281D)/Default.GetContacts

This also requires a setting in the web.config:
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />